# How to convert 4 dimensional array into 2 dimensions and save as csv in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 4 dimensional array with shape `(1, 2000, 102, 32)`

I would like to convert it to `(64000,102)` 64000 is based on (2000*32).

Then store it in csv file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does ordering of the dimensions matter? If not, you can just use numpy reshape function. Example is below.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.zeros((1, 2000, 102, 32))
print(a.shape)
b=a.reshape(64000,102) 
print(b.shape)
```

checkout [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) on how to write it to csv

Comment: Hi, This didn't work out. Cause the shape of the array is 4 dimension and the dimensions are (1,2000,102,32). I want to reduce the dimensions to 2D (64000, 102)

Comment: Quick question, does this reshape place the first 2000 rows and then append next 2000 rows in a sequence?

Comment: Yes. It just flattens everything and follows the normal sequence.